# how to filter/transform object attributes to be serialized with jsonfx?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, jsonfx

I use JsonFX to serialize an instance to json, and I need to ignore some attributes and preprocess others. How do I do that ? The doc is not very clear on that.

My class looks a bit like this one :

```
public class Primitive{
    public string type;
    public float[] vertices;
    public int[] indices;
    public int[] edgeIndices;
    public Scene scene;
```

When outputting json, I need to ignore the `scene` attribute (that's the whole 3d scene) and to pre-process the `vertices`, `indices`, `edgeIndices` using some compression scheme.

And, obviously, I need the symmetrical operation when receiving json.

But how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`[JsonIgnore]`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/JsonFx/JsonFx/JsonIgnoreAttribute) along with [`JsonResolverStrategy`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/JsonFx/JsonFx/JsonResolverStrategy):

```
public class Scene
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // Or whatever
}

public class Primitive
{
    public string type;
    public float[] vertices;
    public int[] indices;
    public int[] edgeIndices;
    [JsonFx.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public Scene scene;
}

public class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var primitive = new Primitive
        {
            type = "some type",
            vertices = new[] { 1.0f, 2.0f },
            indices = new[] { 1, 2 },
            edgeIndices = new[] { 0, 1 },
            scene = new Scene { Name = "Should Not Be Serialized" }
        };

        var writer = new JsonWriter(new DataWriterSettings(new JsonResolverStrategy()));

        var json = writer.Write(primitive);

        Debug.WriteLine(json);  // Prints {"type":"some type","vertices":[1,2],"indices":[1,2],"edgeIndices":[0,1]}
        Debug.Assert(!json.Contains("Should Not Be Serialized")); // No assert
    }
}
```

Or, you can use [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) along with [`DataContractResolverStrategy`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/JsonFx/JsonFx/DataContractResolverStrategy):

```
public class Scene
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // Or whatever
}

[DataContract]
public class Primitive
{
    [DataMember]
    public string type;
    [DataMember]
    public float[] vertices;
    [DataMember]
    public int[] indices;
    [DataMember]
    public int[] edgeIndices;
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public Scene scene;
}

public class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var primitive = new Primitive
        {
            type = "some type",
            vertices = new[] { 1.0f, 2.0f },
            indices = new[] { 1, 2 },
            edgeIndices = new[] { 0, 1 },
            scene = new Scene { Name = "Should Not Be Serialized" }
        };

        var writer = new JsonWriter(new DataWriterSettings(new DataContractResolverStrategy()));

        var json = writer.Write(primitive);

        Debug.WriteLine(json);
        Debug.Assert(!json.Contains("Should Not Be Serialized")); // No assert
    }
}
```

(Note however that `DataContractResolverStrategy` is broken in .Net 3.5., so you can't use it if you're stuck on that old version.)

**Update**

One way to "transform" properties during serialization is to use proxy properties, for instance:

```
public class Primitive
{
    public string type;

    public float[] vertices;

    [JsonFx.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public int[] indices;

    [JsonFx.Json.JsonName("indices")]
    public string compressedIndices
    {
        get
        {
            return indices.Base64Compress();
        }
        set
        {
            indices = CompressionExtensions.Base64DecompressIntArray(value);
        }
    }

    public int[] edgeIndices;

    [JsonFx.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public Scene scene;
}

public static class CompressionExtensions
{
    public static string Base64Compress(this IEnumerable<int> values)
    {
        if (values == null)
            return null;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var compressor = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                var _buffer = new byte[4];
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    _buffer[0] = (byte)value;
                    _buffer[1] = (byte)(value >> 8);
                    _buffer[2] = (byte)(value >> 16);
                    _buffer[3] = (byte)(value >> 24);
                    compressor.Write(_buffer, 0, 4);
                }
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)stream.Length)); // Throw an exception on overflow.
        }
    }

    public static int[] Base64DecompressIntArray(string base64)
    {
        if (base64 == null)
            return null;
        var list = new List<int>();
        var m_buffer = new byte[4];
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)))
        {
            using (var compressor = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                while (compressor.Read(m_buffer, 0, 4) == 4)
                {
                    list.Add((int)(m_buffer[0] | m_buffer[1] << 8 | m_buffer[2] << 16 | m_buffer[3] << 24));
                }
            }
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then write and read like so:

```
        var primitive = new Primitive
        {
            type = "some type",
            vertices = new[] { 1.0f, 2.0f },
            indices = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Select(i => 0).ToArray(),
            edgeIndices = new[] { 0, 1 },
            scene = new Scene { Name = "Should Not Be Serialized" }
        };

        var writer = new JsonWriter(new DataWriterSettings(new JsonResolverStrategy()));

        var json = writer.Write(primitive);

        var reader = new JsonReader(new DataReaderSettings(new JsonResolverStrategy()));
        var primitiveBack = reader.Read<Primitive>(json);

        Debug.Assert(primitiveBack.indices.SequenceEqual(primitive.indices));
```

Comment: thank you, but you cover only half the question, how do I specify a preliminary transformation for the value of an attribute ? in my example, vertices is originally a `float[]`, I want to compress it, the result then would be a `string`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need. I didn't realize that transforming and ignoring would need two different approaches. I am quite new to the c# world.